# Linear Equation of a function

Tags: functions

> A cricket produces 112 chirps per minute at 20 degC, and 180 chirps per minute at 29 degC, Find linear equation that models the temperature T as a function of the number of chirps per minute N.

The linear equation is $T= mN + n$ where $m$ is the gradient and $n$ is the y-intercept

I found $m= \frac{29-20}{180-112} = \frac{9}{68}$

To find the y intercept, I Substituted $(112,20)$, $112= \frac{9}{68} (20)+n $, $ n= \frac{1859}{17}$ But the answer does not agree with the solution of $n= \frac{88}{17}$

I think my answer is correct. Is the solution wrong?

Comment: It looks like you switched your variables around. It should be $20 = \frac{9}{68}(112)+n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two linear equations:
\begin{align}
20 &= m(112) + n \tag{1}\label{1}, \\
29 &= m(180) + n \tag{2}\label{2}.
\end{align}
Subtracting \eqref{1} from \eqref{2} yields
$$m(180 - 112) = 29 - 20 \implies m = \frac{9}{68}. $$
Substituting into \eqref{1} we get
$$ 20 = \frac{9}{68}(112) + n \implies n = 20 - \frac{9 (112)}{68} = \frac{88}{17}. $$